# Loop to display a number increasing by .2 percent 5 times

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble figuring this out. I need to create a loop to repeat 5 times. This loop needs to take integer x and multiply it by .2 and display the result. It then needs to take that result and multiply it by .2 and display the result. It needs to do this 5 times.

```
float credithours;
float tuition = 274.41;


cout << "How many credit hours are you taking this semester? " << endl;
cin >> credithours;
cout << "Your current semester tuition is " << credithours * tuition << endl;

float tuitionfive = credithours * tuition * 2;

cout << "Your tuition for the year is " << tuitionfive << endl;

float tuitiontotal = (tuitionfive * .2) + (tuitionfive);


for (float x = 1; x <= 5; x++) {
    x = tuitiontotal * .2 + tuitionfive;
    cout <<  x << endl;
}
```

Edit *****

I fixed the code after the help here and this is the end result:

```
float credithours;
float tuition = 274.41;



cout << "How many credit hours are you taking this semester? " << endl;
cin >> credithours;

float semestertuition = credithours * tuition;

cout << "Your current semester tuition is " << semestertuition << endl;

float tuitionfive = semestertuition * 2;

cout << "Your tuition for the year is " << tuitionfive << endl; 

cout << "Your tuition for the next 5 years is: " << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
{
    tuitionfive = tuitionfive * .2 + tuitionfive;
    cout << tuitionfive << endl;
}
```

I didn't use the exponent yet, as I need to do some more research to understand it more. Thanks for the help again.

Comment: So where is your code? What have you actually done to solve your problem besides of asking here?

Comment: I just added the code. Edited my original post. I got the loop to repeate 5 times, I just can't figure out how to enter the math equation into it so the equation repeats 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here seems to be the problem, you assign your counter variable out of place. Good practice is to use integer counters (not float), and call it `i`, so that everybody knows it is a counter...

You might be wanting something like this:

```
float tuitiontotal = tuitionfive * .2 + tuitionfive;

for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) 
{
    tuitiontotal = tuitiontotal * .2 + tuitionfive;
    cout <<  tuitiontotal << endl;
}
```

Note, that the `tuitiontotal` variable is that what is increasing five times. But you have to figure out the actual math of what you want yourself... I don't seem to understand what does the .2 do there :]

Comment: That was a really simple fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: The .2 was adding 20 percent tuition increase every year

Comment: UR welcome, now I get it...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Kupto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2217769/kupto)'s answer, you need to have in mind that float in C++ is an approximate value.

Since the value 0.2 is multiplied with the new value, I suggest that you use the exponential value of it.

Something like:   `tuitiontotal *= pow(0.2, i)`

Using pow will reduce the error in the calculation

You'll need to include cmath library, and use pow like: `std::pow(2,3)` which results 8

Comment: I will research that more. I didn't know that float was an approximation. Thank you